# powermail and the special characters

Tags: htmlspecialchars, typo3-4.5, powermail

I have this known issue with special characters < > " & and the powermail extension in Typo3. I already googled and found that it's related to double trigger of the htmlspecialchars in 2 files. I tried many suggestions but they just didn't help. 
 - removed htmlspecialchars from class.tx_powermail_html.php.
 - removed it from class.tx_powermail_markers.php.
 - ...

does somebody has an exact solution to this issue? 
thanks in advance.

Ps: I am using v. 1.6.9 on typo3 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well ,

I could find an answer in case somebody faces the same problem. Just comment out both appearances of "htmlspecialchars" in the function sec() in  "lib\class.tx_powermail_functions_div.php".

That should fix it